# Width and Height 100% doesn't work on pop up image

Tags: html, css, image, frontend, visual-web-developer

I have a contact me button, however, whenever someone hovers over the button, i want a full screen image background to appear. However, this image isn't full screen.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  /*Let's Chat colour*/
}

.Oval {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  top: 510px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-color: white;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 75;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  background: #162129;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Oval:hover {
  position: relative;
}

.Oval:hover:after {
  content: url(Lightning1.JPG);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  center: 100%;
  top: -510px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Oval"><a href="mailto:">Let's Chat</a></div>
```

Comment: can you give me the image? like try to upload it on imgur

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yaoybb9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `pointer-events: none;`+`z-index: -1;` property on `.Oval:hover:after` something like below snippet.

I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.Oval {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  background: #162129;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.Oval:hover:after {
  content:'';
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/QgfTfOU.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Oval"><a href="mailto:">Let's Chat</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS property [position:absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute) precise that:

> It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor

1. If you want the background picture to take all the screen space,
   then it can be achieved with the CSS property [position:fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed)
   with which, you can place it positioned relative to the viewport.
   Then you precise top, bottom, left, right values to `0` to get the
   element to all the viewport.

For example:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  /*Let's Chat colour*/
}

.Oval {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  top: 510px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-color: white;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 75;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  background: #162129;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Oval:hover {
  position: relative;
}

/* Original
.Oval:hover:after {
  content: url(Lightning1.JPG);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  center: 100%;
  top: -510px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
*/

.Oval:hover::after {

    content: url(https://i.imgur.com/QgfTfOU.jpg);
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: -10;
    top: 0;
    border: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="Oval"><a href="mailto:">Let's Chat</a></div>
```

---

---

1. If you want to use the background picture only on the `div.Oval`, then you should you the CSS property `position:absolute`

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  /*Let's Chat colour*/
}

.Oval {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  top: 510px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-color: white;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 75;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  background: #162129;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  clip-path: border-box; /* Added */
  overflow: hidden; /* Added */
}

/* Original
.Oval:hover {
  position: relative;
}
*/

/* Original
.Oval:hover:after {
  content: url(Lightning1.JPG);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  center: 100%;
  top: -510px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
*/

/* Added */
.Oval:hover::after {
  content: '';
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/QgfTfOU.jpg);
  background-size: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 0;
  border: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Oval"><a href="mailto:">Let's Chat</a></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  /*Let's Chat colour*/
}

.Oval {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  top: 510px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-color: white;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 75;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  background: #162129;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Oval:hover {
  position: inherit;
  left:0;
}
.Oval:hover a{display:none;}

.Oval:hover:after {
  content:'';
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/QgfTfOU.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  center: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Oval"><a href="mailto:">Let's Chat</a></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i make the Let's Chat oval not disappear after hovering?

Comment: your expected screenshot share

Comment: When i hover over the Let's Chat i want the background to appear, which did, but i also don't want that button to disappear. Can't take a screenshot since i don't know how to make it work. Sorry                                                                                                         Edit: When you run the code, and hover over the button, the background appears and the button disappears. However, i want both to appear.

Comment: Well... remove that first `.Oval:hover a{display:none;}`

Comment: did that, but I also don't want the button to be transparent, I want it to stay in its original position, and want is so that the background image disappears as soon as I stop hovering over the button.